# Docker with hypervisor

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, hypervisor

I would like to use docker on several different virtualization servers (XenServer, VirtualBox, VirtualMachine etc). Any problem with docker running on them? I've heard docker can run on any hypervisor, AFAIK, but cannot sure and want to know how much performance can docker on hypervisor be made, compared native and just hypervisor. I cannot find any compared information with specific number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that docker uses namespace features of the Linux kernel, there is no overhead to it once a container is started. This also means that it doesn't care whether running on a hypervisor or bare metal. So the only overhead of that of your hypervisor.